# Is reportgenerator in fortify exist some command to filter issue?

Tags: fortify, sourceanalyser

to shorten the work time on handling fortify scanning, i am trying to do some automatic bat. now i have some trouble on filtering the issue of scanning result(*.fpr).

the command i try is
`sourceanalyzer -b %FileName% -scan -filter filter.txt -format fpr -f "D:\%~2%FileName%.fpr" -logfile "%FileName%3.log"`

and the filter.txt content:

```
Insecure SSL: Server Identity Verification Disabled
JSON Injection
```

In the UI(Fortify Audit Workbench) export the filter(*.xml, i find the name of "filter" is "Issue Templates"), you can try the following format to filter the JSON Injection issue in Critical priority order:

```
<Filter>
    <actionParam>true</actionParam>
    <query>[category]:"JSON Injection" AND [fortify priority order]:"Critical"</query>
    <action>hide</action>
</Filter>
```

but it can't be in command line....QQ

i also had tried FPRUtility.bat, BIRTReportGenerator.cmd, and ReportGenerator.bat, but the filter couldn't be custom. does anyone have some advice?

Comment: note that `sourceanalyzer -b %FileName% -scan -format fpr -f "D:\%~2%FileName%.fpr" -logfile "%FileName%3.log" -filter filter.txt` could generate the resulting that I wanted, but this command "delete" the issue instead of "hide", that is bother me.

Comment: now all command does not support the method i wanted, it seems all is Dead end. i think i would try some other way like QuickMacro which can support me controlling the keyboard and mouse click, running in the background